# Connected components and showing subsets are equal

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If $Z_1, Z_2 \subset X $ are connected components, show that $Z_1 = Z_2$ or $Z_1 \cap Z_2 = \emptyset$

Note: we defined connectedness as a splitting of two open sets $U_1$, $U_2$ such that$U_1 = X$ and  $U_2 = \emptyset $ or vice versa

I am having a hard time coming up with anything solid. I thought about contradiction and assuming that my $Z_1$ , $Z_2$ were not connected but nothing came out of that. Maybe I am interpreting the question wrong. Should I use one of the implication to show the other implication?

Comment: What do you know about the union of two connected sets with nonempty intersection?

Answer (score 1):

Prove the following first:

If $X$ is a topological space, and $U,V\subset X$ are connected subsets such that $U\cap V\ne\emptyset$ then $U\cup V$ is connected.